# ServiceStack AppHostHttpListenerBase unable to resolve service dependancies

Tags: c#, servicestack, castle-windsor

I have a ServiceStack AppHostHttpListenerBase configured in my tests with the aim of running tests like so:

```
public class UserProfileBehaviours : BaseTest<UserProfileService>
{
    [Test]
    public void Can_access_secure_service()
    {
        var client = GetClientWithUserPassword();

        var result = ((IRestClient)client).Get(new Dto.View.Requests.UserProfileRequest
             {
                 Slug = "user"
             });

        result.Result.UserAccount.Username.Should().Be("user");
    }
}
```

My BaseTest looks like:

```
[TestFixture]
public class BaseTest<T>
{
    protected TestAppHostHttpListenerBase<T> AppHost;
    private const string ListeningOn = "http://localhost:82/";
    private const string UserName = "user";
    private const string Password = "p@55word";
    protected readonly Container Container;

    public BaseTest()
    {
        Container = new Funq.Container
        {
            Adapter = new WindsorContainerAdapter()
        };
    }

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void OnTestFixtureSetUp()
    {
        AppHost = new TestAppHostHttpListenerBase<T>();

        AppHost.Init();

        AppHost.Start(ListeningOn);
    }

    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public void OnTestFixtureTearDown()
    {
        AppHost.Dispose();
    }

    protected IServiceClient GetClient()
    {
        return new JsonServiceClient(ListeningOn);
    }

    protected IServiceClient GetClientWithUserPassword()
    {
        return new JsonServiceClient(ListeningOn)
        {
            UserName = UserName,
            Password = Password
        };
    }
}
```

And then my WindsorContainerAdapter:

```
public static class CastleWindsor
{
    public static IWindsorContainer InstallFromAssemblies(this IWindsorContainer container, params string[] assemblyNames)
    {
        return container.Install(assemblyNames.Select(
            x => (IWindsorInstaller)new AssemblyInstaller(Assembly.Load(x), new InstallerFactory())).ToArray());
    }
}


public class WindsorContainerAdapter : IContainerAdapter, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;

    public WindsorContainerAdapter()
    {
        _container = new WindsorContainer("Windsor.config");
        _container.Register(Component.For<IWindsorContainer>().Instance(_container));
        _container.Install(FromAssembly.InThisApplication(), FromAssembly.InDirectory(new ApplicationAssemblyFilter())).InstallFromAssemblies("Web.Api");
        _container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("Web.Api").BasedOn(typeof(IRepository<>)).LifestyleSingleton());
        _container.Register(Component.For<IEmailBuilder>().ImplementedBy<EmailBuilder>().LifeStyle.Singleton);
        _container.Register(Component.For<IEmailSender>().ImplementedBy<EmailSender>().LifeStyle.Singleton);
        _container.Register(Component.For<IEmailService>().ImplementedBy<EmailService>());
    }

    public T TryResolve<T>()
    {
        return !_container.Kernel.HasComponent(typeof(T)) ? default(T) :
            Resolve<T>();
    }

    public T Resolve<T>()
    {
        return _container.Resolve<T>();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _container.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And finally my TestAppHostHttpListener

```
public class TestAppHostHttpListenerBase<T> : AppHostHttpListenerBase
{
    public const string WebHostUrl = "http://localhost:82/";
    private InMemoryAuthRepository _userRep;
    private const string UserName = "user";
    private const string Password = "p@55word";
    public const string LoginUrl = "specialLoginPage.html";

    public TestAppHostHttpListenerBase()
        : base("Validation Tests", typeof(T).Assembly)
    {
    }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {

        var appSettings = new AppSettings();

        SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig { WebHostUrl = WebHostUrl });

        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
                        () =>
                        new AuthUserSession(),
                        new IAuthProvider[]
                            {
                                new BasicAuthProvider(),
                                new CredentialsAuthProvider(),
                                new TwitterAuthProvider(appSettings),
                                new FacebookAuthProvider(appSettings)
                            }, "~/" + LoginUrl));

        container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
        _userRep = new InMemoryAuthRepository();
        container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(_userRep);
        CreateUser(1, UserName, null, Password, new List<string> { "TheRole" }, new List<string> { "ThePermission" });
    }

    private void CreateUser(int id, string username, string email, string password, List<string> roles = null, List<string> permissions = null)
    {
        string hash;
        string salt;
        new SaltedHash().GetHashAndSaltString(password, out hash, out salt);

        if (_userRep.GetUserAuthByUserName(username) == null)
        {
            _userRep.CreateUserAuth(new UserAuth
            {
                Id = id,
                DisplayName = "DisplayName",
                Email = email ?? "as@if{0}.com".Fmt(id),
                UserName = username,
                FirstName = "FirstName",
                LastName = "LastName",
                PasswordHash = hash,
                Salt = salt,
                Roles = roles,
                Permissions = permissions
            }, password);
        }
    }
}
```

When the container is being configured I can see that there is a component for `UserAccountRepository` however - if that component is a dependancy for `UserProfileService` the client receives an exception saying that an autowired dependancy couldn't be resolved.
What I don't understand is where does `AppHostHttpListenerBase` get it's container from?

my Windsor adapter is never asked to `Resolve` the component for the repository.

How can I give the `AppHostHttpListenerBase` the container so that it can resolve these dependancies? Or do I need to configure it another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the container adapter at the top of the `TestAppHostHttpListenerBase.Configure` method, instead of within your `BaseTest` class:

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    container.Adapter = new WindsorContainerAdapter();
    ...
}
```

The `Container` object given to the `TestAppHostHttpListenerBase.Configure` method is created in a base constructor of TestAppHostHttpListenerBase; you don't have direct control over its creation. This is the container instance you need to customize with Adapters, etc.

If you also need to use the same IoC container in your `UserProfileBehaviours` or other unit test classes, I think you can reference it via the static `EndpointHost.Container` property, and eliminate the extra container instance that's being created in the `BaseTest` constructor. As implied above, the container object will become available after you instantiate your AppHost object in `OnTestFixtureSetUp`.